# How can I serialize handling of a .net web service?

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, web-services, batch-processing

I'm planning on using a .net web service to batch process database records. The web service requests are coming in from a SQL Server stored procedure that's called by SQL Server Agent every minute. I only want one batch to be running at a time because the whole point here is to avoid over loading the server.

Is there a good way of serializing the requests or maybe rejecting requests if there's already one in progress?

I was thinking of having a web service instance write a flag into the database that subsequent web service instances can read when they start up. If its already set then a web service will return without doing anything. A safe guard could be that if its been ten minutes, say, since the flag was set then the web service instance that set the flag would be considered to have failed.

Any thoughts?

Cheers, Ian.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a static property on the web service to set when it's running, and other instances would check it (after appropriate locking) and fail gracefully, if so. That could take into account your time out, as well.

But is there not an easier way to do this? You seem to be talking about going back and forth from database to web service and back to database again, and for something you want running every minute. Something does not seem quite right. Is there a reason you can't use a Windows service, or even the Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrew. I've been reading about the other two options you mentioned. A Windows Service is a bit low level and requires implementing scheduling which is a case of re-inventing the wheel whilst Windows Task Scheduler sounds unreliable and can result in a CMD window popping up. Yes my plan is ultimately going from database to web service and back again but the initial use of the database is only really for its scheduling feature so I think that's a bit of a red herring!

Comment: I don't think using a static property would work in a web farm scenario. Wouldn't there be one copy of the value on each machine? In fact I'd be suspicious that a static would even be unique on a single machine. Not that that's based on a lot! :)

Comment: But that's what I mean; why have the database doing something just to kick something off, when that's what the Task Scheduler is for. It's not at all unreliable, and there's no reason is has to open a command window at all; It can run a process that has no interface specifically for this sort of thing, and it can manage previously-running instances in much more complexity than you seem to need.

Comment: And correct; a static property would not work in a web farm (or even web garden) scenario... hence my comment about going back and forth (and back again) in and out of a database for something that a single service (Task Scheduler) can take care of for you in one place.

Comment: _"why have the database doing something just to kick something off, when that's what the Task Scheduler is for."_ Because the database scheduler is possibly a more robust scheduler. But if Task Scheduler works OK despite the bad reports I've read then I suppose I might as well use that. If it stops concurrent tasks then even better.

Comment: It lets you define a max time for the process to run, and to skip running a new instance while one is still running previously. My bet would be any complaints you read were either not on a server or really were due to the process being started... not Task Manager itself (such as spawning a window)